# Change the CSS of a ExtJS Column after it has been rendered

Tags: extjs

I have a ExtJS Panel with a number of columns some of which are hidden.

I want to be able to change the CSS of these columns depending on whether the column is set to hidden or not, is this possible?

Comment: What does "column" mean? Is it grid's column or column of panel with column layout?

Comment: @Molecule - Its is a grids column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all there is no such thing as column from DOM's point of view. There are bunch of cells(`div`s and `td`s actualy) that have same className:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| div#gridcolumn-1018            | div#gridcolumn-1019            |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| td.x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1018 | td.x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1019 |  
| td.x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1018 | td.x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1019 | 
| td.x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1018 | td.x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1019 |
|         ...                    |         ...                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So when you are doing thing like:

```
grid.columns[1].addCls('myCls');
```

you are adding class to `div#gridcolumn-1019` but not to all other column's cells.

So to add class to all cells of column on column hiding you have to do something like this:

```
grid.column[1].on('hide', function(column){
  var id = column.getId(); // gridcolumn-1019
  var cells = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-grid-cell-'+id);
  column.addCls('myCls');
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    Ext.fly(cells[i]).addCls('myCls');
}
```

**UPDATE:** changed the incorrect `cells[i].addCls('myCls');` to correct `Ext.fly(cells[i]).addCls('myCls');`

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I just want to point out that the last line "cells[i].addCls('myCls');" doesn't work as cells[i] is a DOM element, but you can just access the css directly

Answer (score 2):

I've never done this before but try this out:

Use `hiddenchange : ( ColumnModel this, Number columnIndex, Boolean hidden )` event of the columnmodel. Get the column using `this.getColumnById(this.getColumnId(columnIndex))` and then access the `renderer` property of the column. Specifically check the `css` config option of the `column` from the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/?class=Ext.grid.Column).